# automation filter query by IsDelete field in model builder ef core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want not to return entity when the flag is `IsDelete=true`. I've written this code for all entities:

```
builder.HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDelete)
```

I want to write a code for all entities in a model builder, not code like one by one in `IentityTypeConfiguration`.

**How can I do this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation requires that you have your entities to implement ISoftDeleteAware interface, so if you have your own interface just rename accordingly:

```
public interface ISoftDeleteAware
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);        
    //Mapping code etc …        
    var versionedEntities = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes();

    foreach (var entityType in versionedEntities)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType, entityBuilder =>
        {
        //Global Filters
        var lambdaExp = ApplyEntityFilterTo(entityType.ClrType);    
        if (lambdaExp != null)
            entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(lambdaExp);
        });
    }
}

protected virtual LambdaExpression ApplyEntityFilterTo(Type entityClrType)
{
    if (typeof(ISoftDeleteAware).IsAssignableFrom(entityClrType))
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityClrType, "entity");            
        var member = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(ISoftDeleteAware.IsDeleted));            
        var body = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(false));                
        return Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thaks . but can you explain your code ?